# How do I change the amount of columns per tab?

Tags: wxpython

Whenever I press tab to indent in my text editor, it does 8 columns instead of 4 which is how much I want. How do I change it to 4?

Here is my text editor:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, "face:Courier New")

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetIndent(4)`

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))
        self.control = stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        self.control.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, "face:Courier New")
        self.control.SetIndent(4)
        self.control.SetIndentationGuides(True)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Window(None, "Text Editor")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl.html